# Cannot convert from int to gift card paging error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, integer, typecasting-operator

I need to add TotalCount to item but get an error like cannot convert int to giftcardpaging.Pls let me know the solution

```
 int TotalCount = count;
 var items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(); 
 List<GiftCardPaging> item = items.ToList();
 item.Add(TotalCount);
 return item;
```

The definition for `GiftCardPaging` is as follows:

```
public class GiftCardPaging {
    public int TotalCount { get; set; } 
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } 
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: So, what are the properties of `GiftCardPaging`?

Comment: string,long,double etc

Comment: `item.Add()` is adding to the `List` - if you want set a property of `GiftCardPaging` you need to do something more like `item[index].MyProperty = TotalCount`

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan I am getting an error like cannot convert int to GiftcardPaging

Comment: That's because `GiftCardPaging` is not an integer. `GiftCardPaging` is an object, made of various properties. It's like giving a builder a brick and expecting a cathedral to magically appear. If you edit in the definition of `GiftCardPaging` I might be able to get my around you're trying to do

Comment: public class GiftCardPaging 
    { public int TotalCount { get; set; }  public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; } }

Answer (score 1):

Now that all the information is available, it seems like this is just a lack of understanding when it comes to Objects.

You've figured out how to count the pages, but the issue that you're not assigning the total properly.

The first point where your code goes off-track is here:

```
var items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(); 
List<GiftCardPaging> item = items.ToList();
```

`items` is already typed as `List<GiftCardPaging>` - the next line serves no purpose. So that could simply be:

```
List<GiftCardPaging> items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList();
```

OK, so now that we've cleared that part up, onto the main issue.

The error you're getting, tells you what the issue is. You can't convert from an integer to `GiftCardPaging`.

When doing something like:

```
myList.Add(myNewItem);
```

`myNewItem` needs to be the same type as you used when you declared the List.

So the question becomes:

Are you wanting to create a new `GiftCardPaging` item (that has `TotalCount` set and add it to the List)? In, which case:

```
int TotalCount = count;
List<GiftCardPaging> items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(); 
GiftCardPaging item = new GiftCardPaging();
item.TotalCount = TotalCount;
items.Add(item);
return items;
```

Or, are you wanting to pluck a certain item from the List and set the value on that? In which case:

```
int TotalCount = count;
List<GiftCardPaging> items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(); 
GiftCardPaging item = items[0]; //for the sake of argument, I'll get the first from the list
item.TotalCount = TotalCount;    
return item;
```

But I'd argue that before all of this, your class structure seems amiss anyway. I think it'd be better to have it set up more like this:

```
public class GiftCard {
    private int GiftCardID; 
    private Contact ContactDetails; //This references a class called Contact where you have the contact details like phone number
    private List<GiftCardPage> Pages; //GiftCardPage could be an object with properties like HeaderText or Content
    //Add any other details relevant to the gift card

    //Throw a class constuctor here (i.e.). 
    public GiftCard(int id, Contact contact) {
        GiftCardID = id;
        ContactDetails = contact;
        Pages = new List<GiftCardPage>();
    }

    //Add pages here 
    public void AddPage(GiftCardPage page){
        Pages.Add(page);
    }

    //Get Page Count
    public int TotalPages() {
         return Pages.Count();
    }

}

public class Contact{
     // name, telephone, etc
}

public class GiftCardPage{
     //Page specific stuff
}
```